# How do I get all the keys from a redis cache via Spring Boot with Spring Data Redis 2.x?

Tags: java, spring, redis

I am trying to get the entries in a Spring Boot Cache backed by Redis [How do I get all the keys from a redis cache via Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48473404/how-do-i-get-all-the-keys-from-a-redis-cache-via-spring-boot) uses 1.x of Spring-Data-Redis and the current version uses `DefaultRedisCacheWriter` for the native cache.

Answer (score 0):

I did this several years ago with spring boot 2 (so not sure if this'll work for you with v1), but what I remember is that the Redis cache is actually built upon a number of caches, each having a name. This is typically setup in a `@Configuration` class. Each cache is then just a map of key-value pairs, which is what the application would supply.

This is just an example for this use-case (where the developer fully controls the caching), as I wasn't really interested in the Spring-annotated methods for caching method responses.

In my configuration class, I create a `CacheManager` object which is configured with the various caches I intend to use within my application, and those would include the names and their TTL values supplied in a hashmap.

Here's some code (untested, so you may need to tweak it):

```
@Autowired
private CacheManager cacheManager;

@Autowired
private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;


public String getValue(String cacheName, String key) {
  cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).get(key);
}

public Map<String, String> getCache(String cacheName) {
    return redisTemplate
      .keys(cacheName+"*")
      .parallelStream()
      .map(key -> {
          Map<String, String> cacheEntries = new HashMap<>();
          cacheEntries.put(key, getValue(cacheName, key));
          return cacheEntries;
        }
      )
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public void getAllCaches() {
  cacheManager.getCacheNames().forEach(cacheName -> {
    Map<String, String> cacheObject = getCache(cacheName);
    cacheObject.entrySet().stream().peek(entry -> {
      System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for me as I don't have a "RedisTemplate" to autowire

Comment: Spring boot docs says it is available: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisTemplate.html

Comment: that's for 1.x I'm on spring-data-redis-2.3.5.  The one I linked to also uses 1.x, hence why I created this one and titlled it explicitly for 2.x

Comment: This code is for all versions. Notice that I did state "spring boot 2" in my post with the code. I originally wrote that code against v2.1.0 You just need to configure your redistemplate/cachemanager objects as annotated beans.

Answer (score 0):

Quite late for op but in case it helps any visitor. I'd a similar requirement:

```
public StringBuffer getAllKeys() {

 
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

   Set<byte[]> keys = redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().keys("*".getBytes());

   Iterator<byte[]> it = keys.iterator();

   while(it.hasNext()){

       byte[] data = (byte[])it.next();
       sb.append(new String(data, 0, data.length));
          }

   return sb;
}
```